# Can I run MS tests from an external file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I am trying to re-run the failed tests as a fresh run in the same batch. Using Test outcome I want to find the failed tests and add them to an external file (XML/any format). When my batch completes the tests, I want the same batch to run failed tests (from XML/Any format) ? Can I do that ??

Comment: Why would failed tests have a different outcome in the same batch if no code changes were made?

Comment: it's automated UI testsing... it's very fragile sometime may not able to find the required objects. So re-run <may> give diff result..

Comment: This seems like a test design problem, not a test run problem. What is to prevent this re-run from happening continuously if a test is failing for a real reason?

Comment: @RonBeyer I understand that but it's a requirement.  It will re-run for just once.. I will have a counter (something like errorcount).. no need to run for ever....

Comment: I think you'd be better off changing the tests which you think may fail so that you use a loop and try catch. If the test code doesn't throw an exception (failed an assert or whatever) then exit the loop. If it does throw an exception then retry the test once.
You're focussing too much on what you think is the solution rather than the problem itself. Your problem is that you want to run a failed test twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one strategy assuming you want to use command line:

- Parse the trx file to find the failed tests and obtain `testId`
- Create a `vsmdi` file with the `testId` of failed tests
- Run the test list as `mstest.exe /testMetadata:<path/to/vsmdi>`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#testmetadata) for documentation.

A detailed post about internals of trx and vsmdi: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhopton/archive/2008/06/12/helpful-internals-of-trx-and-vsmdi-files.aspx

OR,
There's a [wrapper](http://automatetheplanet.com/mstest-rerun-failed-tests-through-mstest-exe-wrapper-application/) over mstest.exe which reruns tests.